# Problem while merging a standard account with a customer portal account

Tags: account, account-management

There are two accounts, one created by a standard user and another created by a customer portal user(Community User).

Now I want to merge these accounts as they are duplicates but while merging SalesForce is not allowing me to pick the standard account(created by standard user) as master record, I can only pick it as a duplicate record.

Is there any reason why SalesForce is restricting this action?

Comment: Is the account created by the portal user the the account enabled for portal access? If so, you can't delete it without deactivating that user's login in the portal.

Comment: How to check that? I see a field IsCustomerPortal is true for that account.

Comment: any news with that? i have the same issue